# Crear un query de SQL en base al nombre de un botón presionado

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos

Hacía mucho que no escribía una pregunta aquí, pero tengo el siguiente trozo de código:

```
try {
    //Creación de query secundario para SQL
    Statement IVSt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet IV = IVSt.executeQuery("SELECT IDProducto as ID, Imagen as ImgURL, Nombre as NomProd FROM productos");
    //Obtiene los enlaces a las imágenes
    System.out.println("Recuperando enlaces...\n");
    while (IV.next()) {
        int i = 0, h = 0; //Variables incrementables.
        //Arreglos | Textos
        //La h se utiliza sólo para el URL de la imagen, ya que utilizar la i
        //ocasiona errores en el programa.
        ImgURL[i] = IV.getString("ImgURL");
        Prod[i] = IV.getString("NomProd");
        System.out.println(ImgURL[i] + "\n" + Prod[i]);
        i++;
        butVal[i] = Integer.parseInt(IV.getString("ID"));
        but[i] = new JButton(Prod[h]);
        but[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon(
        new URL(ImgURL[h]))
        .getImage()
        .getScaledInstance(128, 128, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)))));
        but[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        but[i].setContentAreaFilled(true);
        but[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(JButton.CENTER);
        but[i].setVerticalTextPosition(JButton.BOTTOM);
        but[i].setName(String.valueOf(butVal[i]));
        System.out.println("Botón generado: "+butVal[i]);
        but[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                String value = ((JButton)evt.getSource()).getName();
                System.out.println("Botón presionado: "+value);
                new DatosUI2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        compsToExperiment.add(but[i]);
    }
}
```

Que al ejecutarse crea y ejecuta una solicitud de SQL para obtener datos de una tabla de productos.
Por cada producto, se genera un botón que incluye una imagen adjunta y el nombre de este.
Como nota hay algunos *println* para verificar que se estén recuperando los datos, así como también los botones generados y los que se han presionado.

Al presionar un botón, se abre una ventana con el siguiente código:

```
public DatosUI2() {
    try {
        //Creación de query para SQL
        System.out.println(value);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT IDProducto as ID, Stock as Inv, PrecioUnit as Precio FROM productos WHERE IDProducto = "+value); 
        //Obtiene un recuento de los enlaces a imágenes
        if (rs.next()) {
            Stock = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Inv"));
            Precio = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Precio"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) { System.out.println(ex); }
    SpnMdl = new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,Stock,1);
    initComponents();          
    Lbl_Max.setText(String.valueOf(Stock));  
    Lbl_Precio.setText("$"+String.valueOf(Precio));  
    Lbl_Total.setText(String.valueOf(Precio*Integer.parseInt(Spn_Cant.getValue().toString()))); 
}
```

Que debería obtener el valor del botón presionado (en forma de su nombre) para así obtener el inventario y limitar el *spinner* a la cantidad disponible, así como también crea *labels* que se actualizan para obtener el precio y el total en base a la cantidad seleccionada.

Por desgracia aquí es donde estoy estancado, puesto que no sé cómo enviar el nombre del botón a la otra clase (DatosUI2).
He intentado utilizar variables finales, pero éstas sólo dan errores; también he intentado reasignarlas en el *ActionListener*, pero obviamente no puedo utilizar *but[i]* debido a que sólo puedo referenciar variables finales.
Apenas estoy agarrando la maña de programar en Java, así que hasta donde recuerdo lo anterior es todo lo que he intentado hasta ahora.

Comment: Debido a que estoy algo desorientado por la frustración, iré actualizando la publicación y (posiblemente) limpiaré el código para que sea más legible para los que vean esta pregunta.

Comment: DatosUI2 es una clase como otra cualquiera. Puedes pasarle los parámetros en el constructor, si defines el constructor para recibir parámetros.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco más al respecto? Estaba pensando en usar un ActionListener en DatosUI2, pero no sé cómo enlazarlo con el de DatosUI.

Comment: Pues que si defines el constructor de DatosUI2 para recibir el nombre: `DatosUI2( String nombre)`, cuando haces el new le puedes pasar el valor: `new DatosUI2( "tu nombre")`. Al recibirlo como parámetro, lo puedes usar en el constructor, guardarlo o hacer lo que necesites.

Comment: Lo había intentado la variable *value*, declarada en: `String value = ((JButton)evt.getSource()).getName();`, sin embargo tira error al colocarlo dentro del constructor (`new DatosUI2(value);`).

Comment: De igual forma, ¿cómo podría incluir *value* dentro del query en DatosUI2?

Comment: Si redefines el constructor de la clase para recibir un String, eso debería funcionarte. Tal cual lo tienes, obviamente no. Una vez lo tengas como parámetro en el constructor, que es donde haces la consulta, podrás usarlo.

Comment: Pues como mencioné, el `.getName()` dentro del String *value* no funciona al utilizar `new DatosUI2(value);`. ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal, o malentendí lo que comentaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude resolverlo. En el DatosUI2() tenía que incluir una variable entera que la recibiera de DatosUI(), y luego utilizar esa variable en la solicitud de SQL, es decir:

```
public DatosUI2(int i) /*<--*/ {
    try {
        //...
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT "+/*...*/+"FROM productos WHERE IDProducto = "+i); 
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

De tal forma que pudiera hacer algo como lo que mencionaba [@SuperG280](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/90525/superg280):

```
public void addComponentsToPane(final Container pane) {
//...
    try {
        //...
        while (IV.next()) {
            //...
            but[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    String value = ((JButton)evt.getSource()).getName();
                    int a = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    System.out.println("Botón presionado: "+value);
                    //esta línea: introducir el nombre del botón al abrir DatosUI2()
                    new DatosUI2(a).setVisible(true);
                }
            });
            compsToExperiment.add(but[i]);
        }
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Gracias [@SuperG280](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/90525/superg280) por iluminarme. Llevaba ya más de dos días buscando una solución a este problema.